# SLES 15 SP3 kernel version does not match release (/etc/os-release)

Tags: linux

i've upgraded from sles 12sp5 to sles 15sp3, using 'zypper dup'. seems to be upgraded, showing kernel version of 15sp3, however os-release still showing 12sp5.

here're the details:

uname -a Linux EU-HWS-LNX192 5.3.18-57-default #1 SMP Wed Apr 28 10:54:41 UTC 2021 (ba3c2e9) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

cat /etc/os-release NAME="SLES" VERSION="12-SP5" VERSION_ID="12.5" PRETTY_NAME="SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 SP5" ID="sles" ANSI_COLOR="0;32" CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:suse:sles:12:sp5"

any ideas, please help

Comment: Is this a cloud instance, a "normal" hosted VM, or a physical server? If it is a cloud instance, it might not be possible to upgrade its OS like on a regular virtual or physical server, since instead of maintaining a long-term server image, you're generally supposed to use the cloud deployment tools to re-deploy your applications to a new instance (with possibly an updated OS version), and then tear down the old instance. ("Cattle instead of pets", as the cloud evangelists say.)

Comment: I haven't used SLES in > 15 years ... back then upgrading a kernel required a reboot ... does it still? If it does - did you?

Comment: it's a normal hosted VM, and rebooted it after upgrade.